# My counter does no increase and stays as 1 in java

Tags: java, file, counter

I have a feeling I may have missed something in my code that is preventing my counter from increasing. Can someone check to see what I may have miss, my counter's values stays as 1.

Code:

```
public static void count_vowels(String in_file)
{
    {
        File temp = new File(in_file);
        Scanner input_file;
        try
        {
            input_file = new Scanner(temp);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.printf("Failed to open file %s\n", in_file );
            return;
        }
        while(input_file.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = input_file.nextLine();
            System.out.printf("%s\n", line);
            for(int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++)
            {
                char aA = line.charAt(i);
                int counta = 0;
                if(aA == 'a' || aA == 'A')
                {
                    counta++;
                    System.out.println(counta);
                }


            }

        }
        input_file.close();

    }
}
```

The program calls a file given with 3 lines of text. I added 2 print statements to show the lines and underneath each line the value of the counter is printed. The result is:

```
The CAT is jumping over an airplane.
1
1
1
1
TODAY IS WEDNESDAY.
1
1
UUUu
```

It seems to count but does not increment.

Comment: Move this line outside the for loop int counta = 0;

Comment: thank you for the quick reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem: Your `counta` variable gets reinitialized after each loop call, since it's only existing in the scope of the loop.

```
while(input_file.hasNextLine())  {
    String line = input_file.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("%s\n", line);
    int counta = 0; // Move this here if you want to count every a in each line
    for(int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++) {
        char aA = line.charAt(i);
        if(aA == 'a' || aA == 'A') {
           counta++;
           System.out.println(counta);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move this line out of loop

```
int counta = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int counta = 0;
```

declare this line outside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
while(input_file.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = input_file.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("%s\n", line);
        int counta = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++)
        {
            char aA = line.charAt(i);

            if(aA == 'a' || aA == 'A')
            {
                counta++;
                System.out.println(counta);
            }


        }

    }
```

take counta decleration out of for loop

Answer (score 0):

`int counta = 0;` reset to 0 every time it process line.

move outside the `for-loop`

**Modified code**

```
while(input_file.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = input_file.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("%s\n", line);
        int counta = 0; // moved outside
        for(int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++)
        {
            char aA = line.charAt(i);

            if(aA == 'a' || aA == 'A')
            {
                counta++;
                System.out.println(counta);
            }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved it outside and got the counter to increase. From here how could I have the counter to continue from line to line instead of having it restart after each line. After the first line it counts the x amount of "a" but it reverts back to 0 for the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is, that your right here:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++)
            {
                char aA = line.charAt(i);
                int counta = 0;
                ...
```

Your loop is as often executed as you have character in your line. So for every character your programm is declares `counta` and initializes it as `0`. For every loop your creating a "new" variable, always with the value `0`.

If you hit the character you want(`A` and `a` in your case), your increment `counta` and print it out. For the first time it's okay, but for every further loop your porgramm is declaring `counta` and initalzing it with `0`.

The solution is simple:

Get the declartion and initialzation out of your loop:

```
...
while(input_file.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = input_file.nextLine();
            System.out.printf("%s\n", line);
            //Counta need to be placed right here:
            int counta = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++)
            {
                char aA = line.charAt(i);
                //Counta was here before but thats wrong
                if(aA == 'a' || aA == 'A')
                {
                    counta++;
                    System.out.println(counta);
                }


            }

        }
        ...
```

I hope i was able to help and your understanding your problem better now.